# Deploy TensorFlow probability regression model as Sagemaker endpoint

Tags: tensorflow2.0, amazon-sagemaker, tensorflow-probability

I would like to develop a [TensorFlow probability regression model](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/03/regression-with-probabilistic-layers-in.html) locally and deploy as Sagemaker endpoint. I have deployed standard XGB models like this previously and understand that one can deploy TensorFlow model like so:

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel

tensorflow_model = TensorFlowModel(
    name=tensorflow_model_name,
    source_dir='code',
    entry_point='inference.py',
    model_data=<TENSORFLOW_MODEL_S3_URI>,
    role=role,
    framework_version='<TENSORFLOW_VERSION>')

tensorflow_model.deploy(endpoint_name=<ENDPOINT_NAME>,
                        initial_instance_count=1,               
                        instance_type='ml.m5.4xlarge', 
                        wait=False)
```

However, I do not think this will cover for example the dependency:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
```

Do I need to use script mode or Docker instead? Any pointer would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to add "tensorflow_probability" to "requirements.txt" and both your code and requirements into [dependencies](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/model.html#:%7E:text=Python%20logging%20module.-,dependencies%20(list%5Bstr%5D)%20%E2%80%93,-A%20list%20of) if you are not using source_dir:

```
Model(entry_point='inference.py',
  dependencies=['code', 'requirements.txt'])
```

Comment: Guess with the inference script I can also train locally and only deploy model for inferences/deployment in sagemaker endpoint?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct. I have done just that, the easiest I find is to push the model artefact to S3 at the end of the local training. Here is an good example of what inference.py file would look like for [scikit-learn model](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/advanced_functionality/scikit_learn_bring_your_own_model/code/inference.py).

Comment: another question - sorry - how do you ensure that the deployment environment and local environment use the same versions of packages - e.g. tensorflow - guess this could be defined in the requirements.txt?

Comment: yes, requirements is the way to do that. Just make you are using same versions of frameworks locally as your sagemaker framework (tensorflow). Reinstalling tensorflow in sagemaker FrameworkEstimators can potentially have unforeseen consequences.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a requirements.txt in your source_dir(code) and place tensorflow-probability in it. Sagemaker will install the dependencies listed in requirements.txt before running your script.

Comment: Thanks I think I have seen something along the lines when I did some research last night. Could you possibly add a reference to some example on the Internet?